Is there a limit to body size of CrowCpp applications?
I have a simple endpoint running on C++ using CrowCpp , and when I run a curl request like:
curl -X PUT http://localhost:1234/bla \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'

It works fine, however, if the content within -d (i.e. my json message) exceeds around 1MB, I get the following:

curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Any idea why this is the case?
The same error only happens when I do the above curl request within a C++ client using libcurl.h - which indicates that there might a limit of 1MB on either the curl or CrowCpp.

There is no such limit on curl's end, but it is not unusual for web servers to limit the size of requests. Check the server's configuration.

struggling to find any docs in CrowCpp regarding this. There an option to increase the response body, but does not seem to be for request body

What does the raw response from CrowCpp actually look like?

It does not even reach to my route function, i.e. it somehow gets rejected within the backend of the crow library

It seems like crow complains about "invalid HTTP method" when I enable debugging logs. Though, this error does not occur if my json msg is smaller (i.e. less than 1 MiB)
